# How to make a checkboard?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, int

How to make a checkerboard?

0 is representing white and 1 is representing black

I made them all 0 at first and then tried to add in 1s but it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at unit1.Lesson35CheckerboardTask.main(Lesson35CheckerboardTask.java:33)

                public static void main(String[] args){ 

    int a[][] = new int [8][8];



    for (int test = 0; test < a.length; test++)
    {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
    for (int col1 =0; col1 < 8;col1++)
    {
        a[row][col] = 1;
        col = col + 2;



    }
    row = row + 1;
    col = (col - 6);

    }

                //(this prints it out)      

    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <a[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }




    }


}
```

Comment: And which line is line 33?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a CS homework assignment. My advice for you would be to go through your code by hand and on paper and see where you went wrong with your logic, particularly in your for loops. Hint: Look up what it means to raise ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you in your inner loop, try to perform

```
    col = col + 2;
```

8 times, causing you to access your arrays out of bounds.

To avoid this, you could use the modulo operator `%` to greatly simplify your loop:

```
int[][] a = new int[8][8];
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        a[row][col] = (row + col) % 2;
    }
}
```

This will alternate nicely between `0`s and `1`s throughout the board.